# IDbCommandInterceptor never be called

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have created an application base on Entity Framework. To separate reading and writing of the database, I am trying to use IDbCommandInterceptor.
As for my thought, IDbCommandInterceptor will catch the access from EF to database and I could change the connection into another one.
**Connection is normal,I could get the result from database normally.However, The only embarassed thing is that, my custom DbCommandInterceptor class has even not been called!**

**My custom Interceptor:**

```
public class EFCommandInterceptor: IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("NonQueryExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("NonQueryExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync,  command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ReaderExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ReaderExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ScalarExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogInfo("ScalarExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
    }

    private void LogInfo(string command, string commandText)
    {
        //I add a break point here, but it has never been called;
    }
}
```

**The code to call Interceptor:**

```
var cmdInterceptor = new EFCommandInterceptor();
        System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(cmdInterceptor);
        using (var context = new CSMDBContainer())
        {
            var task = context.T_TASK.FirstOrDefault();
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Remove(cmdInterceptor);
```

**Entity Framework section in configuration file:**

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem is that you are adding the interceptor before the instance of the context. Try to add this `AddInterceptor(new EFCommandInterceptor());` inside context's constructor method

Comment: @FabioLuz Thanks. I have tried moving adding interceptor into context's constructor but it still keeps not working.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolved this issue.
The route is that, my Context class generated by EF inherits **ObjectContext**.

After I rebuilt the edmx file and made the Context class inherit **DbContext**, the issue has gone.